Is there an equivalent of this C++ function in C?
I am trying to implement this function in C, it requires handling different types of data, in C++ I only use a template, but in C I don't know how to handle it.
template<class T> int EEPROM_put(int ee, const T& value) {
const byte* p = (const byte*)(const void*)&value;
unsigned int i;

for (i = 0; i < sizeof(value); i++) foo(ee++, *p++);
return i;
 }

template<class T> int EEPROM_get(int ee, T& value) {
byte* p = (byte*)(void*)&value;
unsigned int i;

for (i = 0; i < sizeof(value); i++) *p++ = foo(ee++);
return i;
}


Try the following, but it only accepts one data type, and the EEPROM_get function is not working.
int EEPROM_put(int ee, u16 value){
    const u8* p = (const u8*)(const void*)&value;
    unsigned int i;

    for (i = 0; i < sizeof(value); i++) {
        eeprom_write_1byte(ee++, *p++); Delay_Ms(10);
    }
    return i;
}

int EEPROM_get(int ee,  u16 value) {
  u8* p = (u8*)(void*)&value;
  unsigned int i;

  for (i = 0; i < sizeof(value); i++) {
      *p++ = eeprom_read_1byte(ee++); Delay_Ms(10);
  }
  return i;
}

Is there a way to have an equivalent in C?

The traditional way is to have the caller remove the type information before calling the function instead, e.g. int EEPROM_put(int ee, u8* value, int value_size).

You could solve it with many different functions, one for each type, macros and generic selection. And considering the simplicity of the functions, you could define them inline and not worry too much about the overhead.

When C++ uses call-by-reference, in C, it's like a pointer. Change to: int EEPROM_get(int ee, u16 *value) { u8 *p = (u8 *) value; unsigned int i; for (i = 0; i < sizeof(*value); i++) { *p++ = eeprom_read_1byte(ee++); Delay_Ms(10); } return i; }

Are there any requirements from the particular EEPROM when it comes to erase/write sizes?

The original C++ code has some problems. Some template T is not necessarily something you can serialize meaningfully byte by byte. There may be padding bytes, pointer members etc which would be completely senseless to store into an EEPROM - you cannot do this for most classes, for example. Which means templates are bug-prone and likely the wrong tool here.
Also why would you return a counter equivalent the size of the passed type? That's useless info to the caller. Surely there's some error info to be obtained from the driver instead?
Instead, you'll want to narrow this down to a few allowed types, those who are serializable byte by byte and actually meaningful to store. You can let the caller worry by that if you make an interface based on bytes instead:
Assuming uint8_t is a character type, the fix in portable C++ to C might look like:
void EEPROM_put (int ee, const uint8_t* value, size_t size) 
{
  for (size_t i = 0; i < size; i++) 
    foo(ee[i], value[i]);
}

void EEPROM_get (int ee, uint8_t* value, size_t size)
{
  for (size_t i = 0; i < size; i++) 
    value[i] = foo(ee[i]);
}

Except there ought to be some meaningful result in the form of EEPROM results.

“Which means templates are bug-prone and likely the wrong tool here.” — huh? no! It just means you should add type constraints. The non-template code isn’t any less error-prone: in both cases you need to cast away the type information. Your code makes this more visible by having the user do it, but good template code hides that while at the same time providing type safety.

@KonradRudolph What are you proposing, a bunch of function overloading instead?

@Lundin There is std::is_trivial_v<T> which still formally allows pointers but checks most other dangerous conditions.

@Abstraction Ok, but be that as it may, the question was also how to port this to C.

(You can implement a restricted amount of types supported in C too, template-like, but it involves "X macros" and won't be pretty.)
